# Getting NullpointerException when trying to start Flashlight

Tags: android, camera, flashlight

Im working on a program where you can start your flashlight in your phone.
I've searched alot and got the same answear on how to do. But when I try to do the same i get a nullpointerException

So my XML is looking like
`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/StrongFlashlight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="143dp"
    android:onClick="StrongFlashlight"
    android:text="@string/flashlightMax" />`
```

And my Code is looking like

```
    public void StrongFlashlight(View view){
    Button strongFlashlightButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.StrongFlashlight);
    camera = Camera.open();
    Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
    camera.setParameters(params);
    camera.startPreview();
    newPhoneImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.flashlight_on);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(newPhoneImage);
    strongFlashlightButton.setText("Strong Light");

}
```

and I've declared `Camera camera;
    Drawable newPhoneImage;`
above the onCreate.

When i press the button for the "Strong Light" I get a nullpointerException at `Parameters params = camera.getParameters();`

So what can I do to fix this? What have I done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Which device are you testing on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because your call to `Camera.open()` returns `null`. This happend when the device doesn't have a back facing camera, as stating in the documentation for [Camera.open()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28%29).

> Creates a new Camera object to access the first back-facing camera on the device. If the device does not have a back-facing camera, this returns null.

However, you could fix this by using:

```
 camera = Camera.open(int);
```

Where the int is a Camera ID as returned by [getNumberOfCameras()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#getNumberOfCameras%28%29). You can find the details of a camera from its ID by using [getCameraInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#getCameraInfo%28int,%20android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo%29).

However, in most cases you can access the front camera with the camera ID 0:

```
 camera = Camera.open(0);
```

Additionally, if a device doesn't have a back facing camera, it is unlikely to have a flash light installed.

You can check the availability of a flash using:

```
boolean hasFlashLight = context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

Answer (score 2):

It means that `Camera.open()` returned null.  You'll have to check for null after you assign your camera variable:

```
camera = Camera.open();
if ( camera == null )
    return;
...
```

Comment: indeed its returning null, but performing a check doesn't solve the issue - why is it null.

Comment: From the docs for open() - "Creates a new Camera object to access the first back-facing camera on the device. If the device does not have a back-facing camera, this returns null."  He likely doesn't have a back-facing camera

Comment: It's null because the device doesn't have a rear camera: [Camera.open()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open())

Comment: Ah, thanks I'll look into that. Now that I think about it I'm pretty sure that's the case here..  Thanks